# Bold text not changing color

Tags: color, lists, bold

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\definecolor{DARKBLUE}{RGB}{8, 94, 179} 
\begin{tightemize}
\item Designed and developed a \textbf{\color{DARKBLUE}Python} based script to web scrape and index over \textbf{1.2 TB} of news, patent and market data. 
\end{tightemize}
```

The text python is not changing color to dark blue...

Comment: What is `tightemize`? Can you provide a complete Minimal working example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages).

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Here's your code snippet wrapped in a minimal example: [code](https://pastebin.com/4qXmr8Pn) [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yug2C.png)

Comment: Can i send an overleaf link ? @Troy

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xptftzdztnxk 
Line 174 @Werner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template you are using assigns a specific color (called `primary`) to the main font.  This cannot be overridden by `\color`.  You have to redefine the main font without that color.  This way you can also include a fix for the missing bold font.

```
\documentclass{deedy-resume-openfont}

\setmainfont[
  Path = fonts/lato/,
  UprightFont = *-Lig,
  BoldFont = *-Bol,
  %Color=primary,
]{Lato}

\definecolor{DARKBLUE}{RGB}{8, 94, 179} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tightemize}
\item Designed and developed a \textbf{\color{DARKBLUE}Python} based script to web scrape and index over \textbf{1.2 TB} of news, patent and market data. 
\end{tightemize}

\end{document}
```

[Demo on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rsqsqqhrbwht)

Alternatively, if you want to keep the default color, you can add your color via `\addfontfeatures`.

```
\documentclass{deedy-resume-openfont}

\setmainfont[
  Path = fonts/lato/,
  UprightFont = *-Lig,
  BoldFont = *-Bol,
  Color=primary,
]{Lato}

\definecolor{DARKBLUE}{RGB}{8, 94, 179} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tightemize}
\item Designed and developed a \textbf{\addfontfeatures{Color=DARKBLUE}Python} based script to web scrape and index over \textbf{1.2 TB} of news, patent and market data. 
\end{tightemize}

\end{document}
```

[Demo on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tfvwgqcqzhrt)

Comment: Deedy-template. Great. :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, this is pretty ridiculous.  I found it by searching `tightemize`.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md

Comment: @Johannes_B It has 354 forks by now.